# Using mixed disks and OpenFiler to create RAID storage

Tags: raid, openfiler

I need to improve my home storage to add some resilience.

I currently have four disks, as follows:

- D0: 500Gb (System, Boot)
- D1: 1Tb
- D2: 500Gb
- D3: 250Gb

There's a mix of partitions on there, so it's not JBOD, but data is pretty spread out and not redundant.

As this is my primary PC and I don't want to give up the entire OS to storage, my plan is to use OpenFiler in a VM to create a virtual SAN.
I will also use Windows Software RAID to mirror the OS.

Partitions will be created as follows:

```
D0 P1:  100Mb: System-Reserved Boot
D0 P2:   50Gb: Virtual Machine VMDKs for OS
D0 P3:  350Gb: Data

D1 P1: 100Mb: System-Reserved Boot
D1 P2:  50Gb: Virtual Machine VMDKs for OS
D1 P3: 800Gb: Data

D2 P1: 450Gb: Data

D3 P1: 200Gb: Data
```

This will result in:

1. Mirrored boot partition
2. Mirrored Operating system
3. Mirrored Virtual machine O/S disks
4. Four partitions for data

In the four data partitions I will create several large VMDK files, which I will "mount" into OpenFiler as block-storage devices, combined into three RAID arrays (due to the differing disk sizes)

In effect, I'll end up with the following usable partitions

```
SYSTEM  100Mb the small boot partition created by the Windows 7 installer (RAID-1)
HOST     50Gb the Windows 7 partition (RAID-1)
GUESTS   50Gb Virtual machine Guest VMDK's (RAID-1)
VG1     900Gb Volume group consisting of a RAID-5 and two RAID-1
VG2     300Gb Volume group consisting of a single disk
```

On VG1 I can dynamically assign storage for my media, photographs, documents, whatever, and it will be safe.
On VG2 I can dynamically assign storage for my data that is not critical, and easily recoverable, as it is not safe.

Are there any particular 'gotchas' when implementing a virtual OpenFiler like this?
Is the recovery process for a failing disk going to be very problematic?

Thanks.